# Is there simple note-taking tool available for Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I am looking for a simple note taking tool for, with only requirement for backing data, and code highlight support

Comment: [Duplicate question?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2343/note-taking-for-school)

Comment: Code highlight, as in syntax highlighting for Markdown?

Comment: yes, syntax highlighting is what I am taking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [CodeBox](http://www.shpakovski.com/codebox/). Simple interface with support for syntax highlighting, sync with Dropbox and etc.. Available in the Mac App Store

Answer (score 1):

The [PearNote](http://www.usefulfruit.com/pearnote/) app is one I can recommend with no caveats. It is simple, beautiful and powerful.

You don't have to use all of its features, but they are there if you ever wish to add audio or video.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called "Stickies" it's an App you already have on your Mac. Very simple but more powerful than most realize. Check it out.